# Head First Java - RMI issues

Tags: java, rmi

I followed the example on the books but i am getting a lot of errors.

I ran rmiregistry.

I then done.

```
java MyremoteImpl
```

which gave me the following error:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyRemoteImpl_Stub
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:160)
at MyRemoteImpl.main(MyRemoteImpl.java:25)
    Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyRemoteImpl_Stub
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyRemoteImpl_Stub
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:434)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
```

MyRemoteClient gives me the following error:

```
java.rmi.NotBoundException: RemoteHello
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:106)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
at MyRemoteClient.go(MyRemoteClient.java:11)
at MyRemoteClient.main(MyRemoteClient.java:6)
```

Here is my MyRemoteImpl code:

```
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class MyRemoteImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote  {

@Override
public String sayHello(){
    return "server says, 'Hey'";    
}

public MyRemoteImpl() throws RemoteException{ 

}

    public static void main (String [] args){

try{
    MyRemote service = new MyRemoteImpl();
    Naming.rebind("RemoteHello", service);
} catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();

} 
    }
}
```

MyRemoteClient Code:

```
import java.rmi.*;


public class MyRemoteClient {
public static void main(String [] args){
    new MyRemoteClient().go();
}

public void go(){
    try {
        MyRemote service = (MyRemote)   Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/RemoteHello");
        String s = service.sayHello();

        System.out.println(s);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
}

}
```

MyRemote Code:

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface MyRemote extends Remote {

public String sayHello() throws RemoteException;

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this has anything to do with the exception you're getting, but you should never declare classes in the default package.

Comment: I did use my own packages i got the same error, so i then used default packages and still had the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I got this error before and found out i had to run **"rmiregistry"** at the folder where **"MyRemoteImpl_Stub.class"** is. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

The Registry doesn't have that class on its classpath. Either you have to run the Registry in such a a way that it does, e.g. LocateRegistry.createRegistry(), or you have to use the RMI Codebase feature so that the Registry and the client know where to get the missing classes from.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in server's main(String[] args):

```
try{
    MyRemote service = new MyRemoteImpl();
    //Naming.rebind("RemoteHello", service);
    Registry registry = LocaleRegistry.getRegistry();
    registry.bind("RemoteHello", service);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Dynamic code downloading using RMI" section documents this issue, which can be
found @  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html

And to quote:

> 6.1 If you encounter a problem running your RMI server
>
> The first problem you might encounter is the receipt of a ClassNotFoundException when attempting to bind or rebind a remote object to a name in the registry. This exception is usually due to a malformed codebase property, resulting in the registry not being able to locate the remote object's stubs or other classes needed by the stub.
>
> It is important to note that the remote object's stub implements all the same interfaces as the remote object itself, so those interfaces, as well as any other custom classes declared as method parameters or return values, must also be available for download from the specified codebase.
>
> Most frequently, this exception is thrown as a result of omitting the trailing slash from the URL value of the property. Other reasons would include: the value of the property is not a URL; the path to the classes specified in the URL is incorrect or misspelled; the stub class or any other necessary classes are not all available from the specified URL.
>
> The exception that you may encounter in such a case would look like this:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.callback.MessageReceiverImpl_Stub
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.callback.MessageReceiverImpl_Stub
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.callback.MessageReceiverImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Compiled Code)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Compiled Code)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Compiled Code)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Compiled Code)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Compiled Code)
    at examples.callback.MessageReceiverImpl.main(Compiled Code)
RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.callback.MessageReceiverImpl_Stub
```

Comment: I have tried everything with rmi://localhost/RemoteHello" but still no luck

Comment: @YK-47 Obviously you *haven't* 'tried everything' at all, otherwise you would have it working.

Comment: There's no evidence here that he's using the codebase feature at all, let alone wrongly. -1